# Variable used as function argument gets changed, affecting the later function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have no idea what is going on, I have spent countless hours debugging my code until I found the weak spot.

### Concept

```
function fnc() {
    var hl = { // hl stands for hyperlink (<a>)
        uid   : ["player.id", "uid"],
        inVal : ["infra.value*", "infrastructure_value"]
    }
    for (key in hl) { .. do the code in block 1 at bottom .. }
}
```

The code should go through the array (object) of values consisting of `id : [text, call]` and bind a `click(fnc(call))` event to an `<a>text</a>` with given `id`.
(Clicking the link launches the same function - it is desired.)

### The Code

This is the code in short:

```
fnc = function(sort_by, direction) {
var qswitch = 1;

if (qswitch == 1) {
    key = "uid"; console.log("#"+key); // #uid
    $("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][1], direction); });     
    console.log(key); // uid

    key = "inVal"; console.log("#"+key); // #inVal
    $("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][1], direction); });    
    console.log(key); // inVal
}

if (qswitch == 2) {    
    $("#uid").unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl["uid"][1], direction); });     
    $("#inVal").unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl["inVal"][1], direction); }); 
}
}
```

### The problem

You can see two blocks of the same code. The first is supposed to work dynamically as described above, but **both links refer to the same function call**. (*<-this is the error*) Binding the events without using a variable works just fine and each link fires it's own `function(parameters)`.

## Is it a bug?

..or am I just dumb and overworked?

Install the tampermonkey userscript, visit any site, open console (F12) and watch the output. Whenever you click a link, it writes what `function(parameters)` it calls. Each of the two links should have different function call. I suggest using [this](http://nptriton.cqproject.net/) blank site.

[theCode.monkey.js](http://nptriton.cqproject.net/theCode.monkey.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
key = "uid"; console.log("#"+key); // #uid
$("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][1], direction); });     
console.log(key); // uid

key = "inVal"; console.log("#"+key); // #inVal
$("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][2], direction); });    
console.log(key); // inVal
```

The problem here is that `key` is overwritten by the second assignment before it's used in the first callback. Event callbacks are not called at the same time as their defining function and their defining function does not wait for them to be run. The easiest solution would be to use two separate variables, but since it looks like I'm looking at an unrolled loop and your code actually looks like this:

```
for(var key in hl){
    //compute i
    key = "inVal"; console.log("#"+key); // #inVal
    $("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][i], direction); });    
    console.log(key); // inVal
}
```

(if `var` is missing, you should add it - undeclared variables reside in the global scope. You don't want them there. In strict mode, they fail completely) (not sure where `i` comes from, but let's assume it's generated in each loop before what is seen) you can use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to capture the value into a new variable in a new scope (remember, javascript uses function scopes):

```
for(var key in hl){
    // compute `i`
    (function(key, i){
        key = "inVal"; console.log("#"+key); // #inVal
        $("#"+key).unbind("click").click( function() { fnc(hl[key][i], direction); });    
        console.log(key); // inVal
    })(key,i)
}
```

now `key` and `i` inside the loop refer to the IIFE arguments, not to the constantly changing variable variables declared outside the loop.

Also note that: if previous values of `i` are not used to generate new ones, then the computation of `i` can be moved into the function body. If they are used - please note that the order of object keys is not guaranteed.

Comment: I haven't heard of IIFE, but I believe this is exactly what I need (if it holds the value it was computed with, instead of refering to a variable). Do arrays suffer from same index uncertainty as objects? Note that `hl={}` but `hl[key]=[]`. Also I don't actually use `[i]`, just plain number `[1]`, but the text postprocessor thought I am inserting links and changed each [key][1] to incrementing value, that's why you thought it was a changable index. (I corrected the question)

Comment: Also now that I understand what's going on, I've changed the title, so someone else can search for it.